# code highlighting

Tags: visual-studio, codehighlighter

I want code highlighting like visual studio.

If user is attaching a code snippept in the article i want to hightlight the code exactly like what visual studio will do.

How can we achieve this.

Comment: Your question is so vague, I am going to suggest looking at the Eclipse or Emacs codebase.

Comment: Are you talking about a website?

Comment: You want code highlighting like Visual Studio? Open a file in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

For example [google-code-pretify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). If you are not talking about code that is contained in a website but e.g. in a desktop application, you should clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/ASPNET/CodeHighlighter/default.aspx

Does this tool do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in PHP you can also use FSHL: http://code.google.com/p/fshl/. Examples are included.